# Issue rollup over sitecollection with filter possibility on each column

Tags: web-part

I want to create a list of all issues from projects in a sitecollection that can be filterd by user input. My idea was to use the CQWP to retrieve the issues and then add gridview like filterfunctionality (textboxes for each column for filter text). 
Looking for a good example I got stuck. I wonder whether using the CQWP is really suitable or whether there are better options? Any good hint or link for a likewise how to example is welcome.

Comment: what are the issues stored in? i presume you mean within site collection you have projects that are stored within a list and within those lists you have a column called issues? and you want to go though all site collections lists that contain a column called issues and display it in one location that is filter capable? or have i got this totaly wrong?

Comment: Hi Ali, within the site collection there are 'project' sites corresponding to a project. Each project has an issue list with e.g. title, assigned to, task status, priority etc. 
I have a cqwp webpart that shows all issues per project. Now I would like add functionality for the user to filter the issues, e.g. by status, assigned to, priority etc .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think what your looking for is PageQueryString to filter within the cqwp webpart.

http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/cqwp-pagequerystring-and-pagefieldvalue.html

or

> 16.In your site, in the CQWP, select Export from the web part's Edit menu. Save the .WEBPART file locally.
>
> 17.Open the .WEBPART file in Notepad and search for "CommonViewFields". Replace the Property tag line of code with the
>   code listed below, using your internal column name and the
>   corresponding field type. It is very important that the field type
>   listed is the correct type for the the data. If the field type is
>   wrong, it won't break the site, but the Item Style won't display the
>   content. Available values are:   ◦Text ◦Note ◦Number ◦Currency
>   ◦Integer ◦Boolean ◦DateTime ◦Threading ◦Lookup ◦Choice ◦URL ◦Counter
>   ◦DisplayOnly (DisplayOnly field type has no storage of its own)
>
> And I have either used or seen these used, but have not seen them
>   documented anywhere:
>
> ◦RichHTML ◦Image
>
> Some field types are easy to figure out.  If we are calling a date,
>   use DateTime. For Title use Text, for body content use RichHTML.
>   String together multiple entries with a semicolon between each pair:
>   Name, RichHTML; Name2, Text.
>
> ```
> <property name="CommonViewFields" type="string">InternalColumnNameGoesHere, FieldType</property>
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> <property name="CommonViewFields" type="string">Comments, Note</property>
> ```
>
> At the end of this article I cover how to find out the field type.
>
> 18.Save the file and import it back into the site. (Add a Web Part - Import - select the .WEBPART file - Upload - Drag and drop the web
>   part onto the page).

http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/articles/customitemstyle.aspx

Comment: Cool, PageQueryString was what I was looking for. Now I only two questions remain: 1) How can I pass the parameter from e.g. a text box to the URL? 2)The CQWP seems to allow only three 'Additional Filters'?

Comment: @Tom check this out, use this method it should solve your issue betwen textbox and url http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/connect-a-query-string-url-filter-web-part-to-another-web-part-HA010250999.aspx for more than three filters your talking about cqwp override for another solution check this out http://sharepointroot.com/2011/06/03/cqwp-with-more-than-three-filters/ both of those solutions should answer your question ;)

Comment: yet I had no time implement the two things, but I think I will come out with the examples. Thanks for your help!!!